# How unabort the aborted fetch

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I aborted, fetched but I couldn't call the fetch again

```
const startFetch = document.querySelector(" #startFetch");
```

```js
const stopFetch = document.querySelector("#stopFetch");

const controller = new AbortController();
const todos = async() => {
  fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos", {
      signal: controller.signal,
    })
    .then((data) => data.json())
    .then((todos) => {
      console.log(todos);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err.message);
    });
};
startFetch.addEventListener("click", todos);
stopFetch.addEventListener("click", () => {
  controller.abort();
});
```

```html
<button id="startFetch">startFetch</button>
<button id="stopFetch">stopFetch</button>
```

I need to un-abort an aborted fetch

Comment: Could be useful to see what the AbortController does, but I guess you could maybe handle the controller state when you call startFetch.

Comment: Move creating the AbortController into the same function

Comment: okay thats working! i set stopFetch event in the todos function then its work

Comment: @Peterrabbit `AbortController()` is a standard web API. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. An aborted fetch closed the connection, you need to make a separate new request. An aborted signal stays keeps that state, you need to create a new signal (and a new `AbortController`).

```js
const stopFetch = document.querySelector("#stopFetch");

let controller;
const todos = async() => {
  controller = new AbortController();
  fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos", {
      signal: controller.signal,
    })
    .then(data => data.json())
    .then(todos => {
      console.log(todos);
    }, err => {
      console.log(err.message);
    }).finally(() => {
      controller = null;
    });
};
startFetch.addEventListener("click", todos);
stopFetch.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (controller) {
    controller.abort();
  } else {
    console.log("no active request");
  }
});
```

```html
<button id="startFetch">startFetch</button>
<button id="stopFetch">stopFetch</button>
```